# Unable to access WordPress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, admin, panel

I am Unable to access my WordPress admin panel. I have tried all the solutions like changing passwords, config.php file as well as functions.php. I have even tried to deactivate all plugins and then activated them and it has a memory limit also around 256M. While debugging I have found this error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/ausmoulding/public_html/new/wp-content/themes/x/framework/functions/global/plugins/woocommerce.php:196)
>   in /home/ausmoulding/public_html/new/wp-login.php on line 390

It's in the Woocommerce plugin,but I have deleted that plugin and installed a fresh one still it gives me this error.

Comment: yes do one thing try to change the theme. If you have fresh instance then change the existing if not then change with default theme

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the plugin has been coded incorrectly and is trying to perform a redirect after output has been written to the browser HTTP header.

Here's some more info about it in another question: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Either stop using the plugin, or contact the developers.

Comment: But I need that plugin for the website.

Comment: Then get in touch with the developers, as they have alot more knowledge about it than me.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer
```

Could you please add above code in your `functions.php` and try to login?

Comment: Thanks Purvik for answer,but I have tried the code and its still not working.